# English pronunciation: I'm sorry for your loss

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

the phrase "I'm sorry for your loss" phonetically looks like [aɪm **sɔri** fər_yər **lɔs**]. When I heard this phrase in a movie, it seemed that the words "sorry" and " loss" were a bit more louder, but I may be wrong. I think the strongest emphasis is on the last word "loss". I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: You could emphasize almost any word in that sentence (the exception being "for", which I have a hard time justifying) and it would be valid.

Comment: It tends to be a ritualistic statement and both *for* and *your* are often more articulated (no schwa) than in conversational speech.

Comment: What you suggest is exactly what I'd say, except that I say /sari/ instead of /sɔri/.

Comment: bib- for me sounds like both "for" and "your" are reduced https://clyp.it/xpg3ngzt
the sound is from an American TV series.

Comment: That is why I said *often*.

Comment: I think your description is accurate.  Using SPE-like notation, we could write [aɪm 2sɔri fər yər 1lɔs] to transcribe the secondary and primary stresses.

Comment: Greg- You're right. I cut out the same phrase from another episode: https://clyp.it/hk324uc5 This one sounds like it uses yoʊr, but in my opinion the difference between "yoʊr" and reduced "yər" are hard to notice in fast speech.

Comment: at least if they are not in a stressed position.

Comment: Your observation may be correct, but I don't see a question.

Answer (score 1):

In my dialect, the emphasis on the words 'sorry' and 'loss' is by far the strongest, and I think 'sorry' gets a little bit more than 'loss.'